# Stopped maven install

Tags: java, maven

I am testing a spring boot project with it default pom.xml like that.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>   
</project>
```

When I am trying to run the command `mvn clean install` the below two exceptions ProjectBuildingException and UnresolvableModelException appeared like below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.4.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\User\Desktop\demo\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.4.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.240.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: Please show full log output ....

Comment: Looks like a network/firewall/proxy issue `failed: Connection timed out:`

Answer (score 1):

The original log shows that the attempt to connect to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 timed out. This is a, presumably temporary, network problem.

Answer (score 1):

This exactly same pom works fine for me without any change. must be some firewall blocking your connections to https://repo.maven.apache.org

check if you can open this from internet browser if yes, check network connections settings in your IDE and put proxy settings if required.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\Workspace\demo -Dmaven.home=D:\Portables\IdeaIC-2019.2.3.win\plugins\maven\lib\maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=D:\Portables\IdeaIC-2019.2.3.win\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf -Dmaven.ext.class.path=D:\Portables\IdeaIC-2019.2.3.win\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar -javaagent:D:\Portables\IdeaIC-2019.2.3.win\lib\idea_rt.jar=1330:D:\Portables\IdeaIC-2019.2.3.win\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\Portables\IdeaIC-2019.2.3.win\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.2.3 clean compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom (8.1 kB at 4.1 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom (127 kB at 83 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.10.2/jackson-bom-2.10.2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.10.2/jackson-bom-2.10.2.pom (13 kB at 20 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-parent/2.10/jackson-parent-2.10.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-parent/2.10/jackson-parent-2.10.pom (8.3 kB at 13 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/oss-parent/38/oss-parent-38.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/oss-parent/38/oss-parent-38.pom (23 kB at 36 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/micrometer/micrometer-bom/1.3.2/micrometer-bom-1.3.2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/micrometer/micrometer-bom/1.3.2/micrometer-bom-1.3.2.pom (6.6 kB at 10 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-bom/4.1.45.Final/netty-bom-4.1.45.Final.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-bom/4.1.45.Final/netty-bom-4.1.45.Final.pom (7.9 kB at 11 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-bom/Dysprosium-SR4/reactor-bom-Dysprosium-SR4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-bom/Dysprosium-SR4/reactor-bom-Dysprosium-SR4.pom (4.1 kB at 6.4 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/rsocket/rsocket-bom/1.0.0-RC5/rsocket-bom-1.0.0-RC5.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/rsocket/rsocket-bom/1.0.0-RC5/rsocket-bom-1.0.0-RC5.pom (3.0 kB at 4.6 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-bom/2.12.1/log4j-bom-2.12.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-bom/2.12.1/log4j-bom-2.12.1.pom (7.2 kB at 11 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-bom/9.4.25.v20191220/jetty-bom-9.4.25.v20191220.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-bom/9.4.25.v20191220/jetty-bom-9.4.25.v20191220.pom (17 kB at 27 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-bom/2.29.1/jersey-bom-2.29.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-bom/2.29.1/jersey-bom-2.29.1.pom (19 kB at 28 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/ee4j/project/1.0.5/project-1.0.5.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/ee4j/project/1.0.5/project-1.0.5.pom (13 kB at 21 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-bom/1.3.61/kotlin-bom-1.3.61.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-bom/1.3.61/kotlin-bom-1.3.61.pom (8.8 kB at 14 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-bom/1.3.3/kotlinx-coroutines-bom-1.3.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-bom/1.3.3/kotlinx-coroutines-bom-1.3.3.pom (5.0 kB at 7.8 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.5.2/junit-bom-5.5.2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.5.2/junit-bom-5.5.2.pom (4.4 kB at 7.0 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-5.2.3.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-5.2.3.RELEASE.pom (5.3 kB at 8.4 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Moore-SR4/spring-data-releasetrain-Moore-SR4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Moore-SR4/spring-data-releasetrain-Moore-SR4.pom (4.8 kB at 7.6 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-build/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-data-build-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-build/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-data-build-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom (7.1 kB at 11 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-bom/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-integration-bom-5.2.3.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-bom/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-integration-bom-5.2.3.RELEASE.pom (9.0 kB at 14 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-bom/5.2.1.RELEASE/spring-security-bom-5.2.1.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-bom/5.2.1.RELEASE/spring-security-bom-5.2.1.RELEASE.pom (5.4 kB at 8.6 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/session/spring-session-bom/Corn-RELEASE/spring-session-bom-Corn-RELEASE.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/session/spring-session-bom/Corn-RELEASE/spring-session-bom-Corn-RELEASE.pom (2.8 kB at 4.4 kB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.1.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.1.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.1.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.1.0.pom (5.2 kB at 8.2 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/31/maven-plugins-31.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/31/maven-plugins-31.pom (10 kB at 16 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/31/maven-parent-31.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/31/maven-parent-31.pom (43 kB at 65 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.1.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.1.0.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.1.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.1.0.jar (30 kB at 35 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/3.1.0/maven-resources-plugin-3.1.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/3.1.0/maven-resources-plugin-3.1.0.pom (7.2 kB at 11 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/3.1.0/maven-resources-plugin-3.1.0.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/3.1.0/maven-resources-plugin-3.1.0.jar (32 kB at 38 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.pom (12 kB at 19 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.jar (62 kB at 88 kB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.7.1/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.7.1/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.pom (770 B at 1.2 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-containers/1.7.1/plexus-containers-1.7.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-containers/1.7.1/plexus-containers-1.7.1.pom (5.0 kB at 7.8 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.2.1/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.2.1/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.pom (5.6 kB at 8.1 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.7.1/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.2.1/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.7.1/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar (4.3 kB at 5.9 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.2.1/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar (167 kB at 71 kB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.1.0/plexus-utils-3.1.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.1.0/plexus-utils-3.1.0.pom (4.7 kB at 7.3 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.1.0/plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.1.0/plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar (262 kB at 175 kB/s)
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/0.9.10/plexus-java-0.9.10.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/0.9.10/plexus-java-0.9.10.pom (5.1 kB at 8.0 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-languages/0.9.10/plexus-languages-0.9.10.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-languages/0.9.10/plexus-languages-0.9.10.pom (4.1 kB at 6.5 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.2/asm-6.2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.2/asm-6.2.pom (2.9 kB at 4.6 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.5/ow2-1.5.pom (11 kB at 18 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M9/qdox-2.0-M9.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M9/qdox-2.0-M9.pom (16 kB at 23 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-api-2.8.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-api-2.8.4.pom (867 B at 1.4 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-2.8.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-2.8.4.pom (6.0 kB at 9.5 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-manager-2.8.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-manager-2.8.4.pom (692 B at 1.1 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-javac-2.8.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-javac-2.8.4.pom (771 B at 1.2 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/2.8.4/plexus-compilers-2.8.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/2.8.4/plexus-compilers-2.8.4.pom (1.3 kB at 2.1 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/0.9.10/plexus-java-0.9.10.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M9/qdox-2.0-M9.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-api-2.8.4.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.2/asm-6.2.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-manager-2.8.4.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/0.9.10/plexus-java-0.9.10.jar (39 kB at 42 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-api-2.8.4.jar (27 kB at 29 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-javac-2.8.4.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-javac-2.8.4.jar (21 kB at 13 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.8.4/plexus-compiler-manager-2.8.4.jar (4.7 kB at 2.7 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.2/asm-6.2.jar (111 kB at 42 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M9/qdox-2.0-M9.jar (317 kB at 96 kB/s)
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  44.402 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-20T16:59:52+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove relativePath from parent tag

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Will not solve the problem cause it's related to something different. Apart from that the relativePath configuration is correct.

Comment: can you paste the full pom?

Comment: can you access to the repo directly? seems you had a timeout, so some network issues, try to access to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom